# not displaying other result on specific radio button selected

Tags: php, mysql, database, mysqli

Using 4 radio button as option to select the payment column to SUM all the number up. I　wrote if select is equals to first then run first query, and if it's second to run second query.  It's displaying on the first payment even if I select second.  Is it because of my echo at the end of the code?  Can anyone help please?  Should be using `for`?

**HTML Coding (paycal.html):**

```
<body>
<form name="input" action="paycal.php" method="post">
<fieldset>
<legend>Which payment do you want to SUM up:</legend>
    <input type="radio" name="payment" value="first" /> First 
    <input type="radio" name="payment" value="second" /> Second
    <input type="radio" name="payment" value="third"  /> Third
    <input type="radio" name="payment" value="fourth"  /> Fourth

</fieldset>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />   
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

**PHP Coding (paycal.php):**

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set("display_errors", 1);


$pay=$_REQUEST['payment']; 

// MySQL database connection, username, password, database name
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","username","password","database_name");

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

if ($pay=="first") $query="SELECT *, SUM(first_payment) FROM `Customer Information`";
else if ($pay=="second") $query="SELECT *, SUM(second_payment) FROM `Customer Information`";
else if ($pay=="third") $query="SELECT *, SUM(third_payment) FROM `Customer Information`";
else if ($pay=="fourth") $query="SELECT *, SUM(fourth_payment) FROM `Customer Information`";


$result = mysqli_query($query);

// Executing and error checking of query
if (!mysqli_query($con,$query)) {
  die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
}

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

 echo $row['first_payment'];
}

// Close MySQL
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: This table design smacks of poor normalization. I'd fix that first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo $row[$pay.'_payment'];
}
```

Simply make the key produced dynamic using the variable you use which is (`$pay`)

In other thoughts, this is very bad table design. If you had a better design you wouldn't fall into such problems. I suggest you change it.

Comment: Thank you! By table design are you directing to the whole database table?

If it's the database it's because it's calculating interest with DATEDIFF with the amount a client invested, so it's seperated into 4 payments with specific interest rate.  I am not quite sure what other design could I go for, if you could provide me a little more details.  I would love to improve the design.

Answer (score 1):

What do you want to display with:

```
 echo $row['first_payment'];
```

?

you have to switch the column, if you want to display different results.

```
switch($pay)
{
   case "first":
      echo $row['first_payment'];
      break;
   case "second":
      echo $row['second_payment'];
      break;
   case "third":
      echo $row['third_payment'];
      break;
   case "fourth":
      echo $row['fourth_payment'];
      break;
   default:
      echo "nothing selected";
}
```

OR:

adjust your sql to something like this:

```
SELECT SUM(first) as paymentSum From ...
```

and use it

```
echo $row['paymentSum'];
```

Comment: yes, I understand that but if my html has given the option to select which payment to display how would i be able to make it so if the user choose first payment then it will display the first one, and second one if second payment option is chose from the html side.

Comment: you already made the switch with your sql queries... `if($pay==xxx)`

Comment: yes, i have to made that in the code, but when i click submit now it's only showing first_payment even though when I select second payment to be displayed.

Comment: yeah, because you echo $row['first_payment'] !!! you have to echo the corresponding column from your database ;)

Comment: thank you, but by stating what you wrote above is only creating multiple output at once.

i just want one result not all of them that's the reason why i wrote `if`. 

for example from the HTML side i choose second payment once i click submit it will return me only ONE output which is the sum of all second payment.  instead of showing me all 4 payments output at once.